# Failure of Importing data from Bigquery to GCS

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

Dear support at Google,

We recently noticed that many of the GAP site import jobs extracting&uploading data from Google Bigquery to Google Cloud Service have been failing (Since April 4th). Our uploading jobs are running fine before April 4th but have been failing since April 4th, after did investigation, we feel this is an issue/error from Bigquery side, not from our job. The details of error info from Bigquery API when uploading data is shown below:

216769 [main] INFO  org.mortbay.log  - Dataset : 130288123
217495 [main] INFO  org.mortbay.log  - Job is PENDING waiting 10000 milliseconds...
227753 [main] INFO  org.mortbay.log  - Job is PENDING waiting 10000 milliseconds...
237995 [main] INFO  org.mortbay.log  - Job is PENDING waiting 10000 milliseconds...
Heart beat
248208 [main] INFO  org.mortbay.log  - Job is PENDING waiting 10000 milliseconds..
258413 [main] INFO  org.mortbay.log  - Job is PENDING waiting 10000 milliseconds...
268531 [main] INFO  org.mortbay.log  - Job is RUNNING waiting 10000 milliseconds...
Heart beat
**278675 [main] INFO  org.mortbay.log  - An internal error has occurred

278675 [main] INFO  org.mortbay.log  - ErrorProto : null**
 
As per log, it is an internal error with the issue ErrorProto:null.
 
Our google account: ea.eadp@gmail.com
 
Our Google Big Query projects:
    Origin-BQ              origin-bq-1
    Pulse-web             lithe-creek-712

The importing failure on following data set:
 
In Pulse-web, lithe-creek-712:
101983605
130288123
48135564
56570684
57740926
64736126
64951872
72220498
72845162
73148296
77517207
86821637
 
 
Please look into this and let us know if you have any updates.
Thank you very much and looking forward to hearing back from you.
 
Thanks

Comment: You should rather post such issues at a [BigQuery Issue Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/)

Comment: For the sake of posterity, this is the issue tracked in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37010652.